# Gparted: how can I extend the disk when the unallocated is on the upper side？

Tags: partition, disk, gparted

[image: Screenshot of gparted]

How can I extend my ext4 partition?
The swap is off, and there is a lot of unallocated space in front of the ext4 partition.

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: You have 7 ext4 partitions. Please [edit] your question (don't answer in the comments) and specify which partition you want to extend.

Comment: Make sure you have good backups. And move left is a copy and any interruption totally corrupts data. You have to use live installer as little key icons say partition is mounted & then cannot be edited. Alternatives are to move just /home or create data partition(s) for just the data in /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting  The /home or data partition does not have to be on a separate drive.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to resize nvme0n1p8. The reason you cannot do it is because the partition is mounted and GParted shows a lock symbol against that partition. To resize it do the following:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose.
2. It looks like you may have other Linux installations on this machine. If you can boot one of those do so and run GParted from there. You may need to install it first. If you don’t have another Linux installation you will need to boot a live environment, such as that provided by the Ubuntu installer. Choose “Try Ubuntu” don’t reinstall.
3. Once you have GParted running you should see no lock symbol next to nvme0n1p8 and you will be able to use the GParted user interface to change the size of that partition. Don’t forget to click apply for the resize to happen. In this instance it will take some time for this to complete. If you interrupt prematurely it will not end well.

Good luck

Comment: To clarify this answer: Part 3: a) Because the unallocated section comes **before** the drive you want to add it to, you need to minus the position, on the GParted interface. b) by "it will take some time for this to complete" this means it will take **hours** not minutes. Don't rush it.